# str_replce() not working in loop foreach?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$str = array(
    '1' => 'abc',
    '2' => 'def',
    '3' => 'abc'
);
foreach($str as $element) {
$str_rep = str_replace('abc', '123', $str); 
}
echo $str_rep;
```

OUTPUT:

```
$str = array(
    '1' => 'abc',
    '2' => 'def',
    '3' => '123'
);
```

> Error when '1' => 'abc' not replaced ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

A more readable approach:

```
foreach($str as $key => $value) {
    $str[$key] = str_replace('abc', '123', $value); 
}
```

Suggest to replace `$str` with something like `$strArray`, the original name is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$str = array(
    '1' => 'abc',
    '2' => 'def',
    '3' => 'abc'
);
foreach($str as &$element) {
    $element = str_replace('abc', '123', $element); 
}
print_r($str);
```

I changed your foreach to use values by reference

**The real problem was you were replacing your output variable ($str_rep) each time in the loop.  So of course it will only output the last change! :)**

Answer (score 0):

In your `foreach` loop, you're not referring to your value. Try this:

```
foreach($str as $element) {
    $str_rep = str_replace('abc', '123', $element); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this:

```
<?

$str = array(
    '1' => 'abc',
    '2' => 'def',
    '3' => 'abc'
);
foreach($str as &$element) {
$str_rep = str_replace('abc', '123', $str);
}
var_dump($str_rep);
?>
```

And it seems to work fine?

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
foreach($str as $element) {
$str_rep = str_replace('abc', '123', $element); 
}
```